# Is there a way to have all my object files in the same directory using Make?

Tags: c, makefile

So, I decided to learn make as my first step into large projects, and I have to say that it is not that hard if you are just doing simple tasks and got addicted to it.
However I usually work with a scheme for my directories:

```
.
├── build
├── include
│   └── func.h
├── lib
│   └── func.c
├── Makefile
└── src
    └── main.c
```

I usually have all my object files spread in the build directory. However, I could only map the source files to the build folder (like ./build/src/main.o where I prefer ./build/main.o).
I Tried Reading The Documentation to no avail!
this is what I came up with so far:

```
# C Compiler
CC                  = gcc

#------------- Directories
SOURCE_DIR          = src lib
OBJECTS_DIR         = build
INCLUDE_DIR         = . ./include
#----------------------------

VPATH               = $(SOURCE_DIR)

#------------- Files
SOURCE              = $(foreach dir,    $(SOURCE_DIR),  $(wildcard  $(dir)/*.c))
# Fake Objects (Just so I can map them to c files)
FOBJECTS            = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(SOURCE:.c=.o))
OBJECTS             = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(notdir $(FOBJECTS)))
DEPS                = $(foreach dir,    $(INCLUDE_DIR), $(wildcard  $(dir)/*.h))
#----------------------------

#------------- Flags
OPT                 = -O0
IFLAGS              = $(foreach dir,    $(INCLUDE_DIR), -I$(dir))
LFLAGS              = -lm
CFLAGS              = -Wall
FLAGS               = $(OPT) $(IFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
#----------------------------

BINARY              = bin

all                 : $(BINARY)

$(BINARY)           : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS)          : $(FOBJECTS)
    mv -t $(OBJECTS_DIR) $(FOBJECTS) 
    rm -rf -- $(OBJECTS_DIR)/*/

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o  : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

exec                : $(BINARY)
    @./$(BINARY)

clean               :
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(BINARY)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
gcc                      -O0  -I.  -I./include -lm -Wall -c -o build/src/main.o src/main.c
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/src/main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:39: build/src/main.o] Error 1
```

I know the reason is the Fake Objects I created but creating the perfect rule for this is hard

Comment: if you plan to work on large projects, you should probably look at a build chain generator like cmake. Writing makefiles for large project is just a pain and very hard to maintain.

Comment: I'm guessing you want: (A) `build/main.o` and `build/func.o` But, the make wants: (B) `build/src/main.o` and `build/lib/func.o`. Having done this before, I'd like to suggest that you _do_ want (B). Comingling `.o` files from different subprojects (e.g. various programs and libraries) isn't what you'd want. So, to do (B), you just need to do `mkdir build/src build/lib`

Comment: @OznOg You see, I always want to learn how things work before abstracting them. I will probably switch soon, but not till I understand this.

Comment: @CraigEstey , Are you sure? I feel more comfort when I can see all the files together. It's not for any practical reason.

Comment: Absolutely. Consider that your make is a top level for _all_ your projects. For example, you have many different libraries (e.g. libnet, libprime, libcollatz, libfft) and they do _not_ interact. They are separate. It makes no sense to put the `.o` in the same directory

Comment: The main reason to not use a single objects directory is, what if you have both `lib/misc.c` and `src/misc.c`?  In any event, you needn't be worried too much about what your objects subdirectories look like.  Those are the purview of the build system and you won't need to go looking around in there.  So what is the advantage of "seeing all of the (object) files together"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, you probably do *not* want to put all `.o` in the same directory because comingling `.o` files from unrelated projects isn't the best organization. If the `.o` files *were* related, you'd probably put the `.c` files in the same subdir.

---

But, if you did want *all* `.o` in a single `build` directory, one way is to create the `build/*` subdirs:

```
# C Compiler
CC                  = gcc

#------------- Directories
SOURCE_DIR          = src lib
OBJECTS_DIR         = build
INCLUDE_DIR         = . ./include
OBJ_MK              = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(SOURCE_DIR))
#----------------------------

VPATH               = $(SOURCE_DIR)

#------------- Files
SOURCE              = $(foreach dir,    $(SOURCE_DIR),  $(wildcard  $(dir)/*.c))
# Fake Objects (Just so I can map them to c files)
FOBJECTS            = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(SOURCE:.c=.o))
OBJECTS             = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(notdir $(FOBJECTS)))
DEPS                = $(foreach dir,    $(INCLUDE_DIR), $(wildcard  $(dir)/*.h))
#----------------------------

#------------- Flags
OPT                 = -O0
IFLAGS              = $(foreach dir,    $(INCLUDE_DIR), -I$(dir))
LFLAGS              = -lm
CFLAGS              = -Wall
FLAGS               = $(OPT) $(IFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
#----------------------------

BINARY              = bin

all                 : $(OBJ_MK) $(BINARY)

$(BINARY)           : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS)          : $(FOBJECTS)
    mv -t $(OBJECTS_DIR) $(FOBJECTS)
    rm -rf -- $(OBJECTS_DIR)/*/

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o  : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

exec                : $(BINARY)
    @./$(BINARY)

clean               :
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(BINARY)
    rm -rf $(OBJ_MK)

$(OBJ_MK):
    mkdir $@
```

The `make` output is:

```
mkdir build/src
mkdir build/lib
gcc -O0  -I.  -I./include -lm -Wall -c -o build/src/main.o src/main.c
gcc -O0  -I.  -I./include -lm -Wall -c -o build/lib/func.o lib/func.c
mv -t build build/src/main.o build/lib/func.o
rm -rf -- build/*/
gcc -o bin build/main.o build/func.o
```

---

However, the above actually makes the build more complex because its "natural" tendency was to create the subdirs. To override that required extra `mv` and `rm` commands.

To use the subdirectory method, the build is actually simpler, and we can do:

```
# C Compiler
CC                  = gcc

#------------- Directories
SOURCE_DIR          = src lib
OBJECTS_DIR         = build
INCLUDE_DIR         = . ./include
OBJ_MK              = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(SOURCE_DIR))
#----------------------------

VPATH               = $(SOURCE_DIR)

#------------- Files
SOURCE              = $(foreach dir,    $(SOURCE_DIR),  $(wildcard  $(dir)/*.c))
# Fake Objects (Just so I can map them to c files)
OBJECTS             = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(SOURCE:.c=.o))
DEPS                = $(foreach dir,    $(INCLUDE_DIR), $(wildcard  $(dir)/*.h))
#----------------------------

#------------- Flags
OPT                 = -O0
IFLAGS              = $(foreach dir,    $(INCLUDE_DIR), -I$(dir))
LFLAGS              = -lm
CFLAGS              = -Wall
FLAGS               = $(OPT) $(IFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
#----------------------------

BINARY              = bin

all                 : $(OBJ_MK) $(BINARY)

$(BINARY)           : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o  : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

exec                : $(BINARY)
    @./$(BINARY)

clean               :
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(BINARY)
    rm -rf $(OBJ_MK)

$(OBJ_MK):
    mkdir $@
```

The `make` output is:

```
mkdir build/src
mkdir build/lib
gcc -O0  -I.  -I./include -lm -Wall -c -o build/src/main.o src/main.c
gcc -O0  -I.  -I./include -lm -Wall -c -o build/lib/func.o lib/func.c
gcc -o bin build/src/main.o build/lib/func.o
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want all the objects in a single directory, you almost have it right but you added some very strange rules that I don't understand; what is this for:

```
$(OBJECTS) : $(FOBJECTS)
        mv -t $(OBJECTS_DIR) $(FOBJECTS) 
        rm -rf -- $(OBJECTS_DIR)/*/
```

?  This is what's causing your problem.  You're saying that every individual object file depends on all the "intermediate" object files, so then make tries to build these "intermediate" object files.  The only way it knows to do that is with the pattern rule you provided, but that doesn't build those files.

Remove that rule altogether and it will probably work.  You just want:

```
VPATH = $(SOURCE_DIR)

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.c=.o)))

all : $(BINARY)

$(BINARY) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o  : %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

etc.  The compiler will build the object files directly into their final destination.  You don't need the `FOBJECTS` thing or the rule that uses it.