# How to use Makefile for .c program which needs to be imported to Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I was trying to execute Makefile and wanted to execute a C program with it. First, how can I include `test.c` file for makefile?

I've placed makefile in root directly as there will be other .c files later added.
Can anyone hep me executing this?

File structure:
[image]

Makefile code so far not working (it will work if I place it inside src still not getting the output of file.)

```
# -o : object file


Test: test.c
    gcc -o Test test.c
```

Glad if anyone can help or suggest anything!

Comment: Makefiles are not C source files; why do you have `#include "src/test.c"` in it?

Comment: *"i was trying to execute Makefile"* - um.. what?? I advise investing time with the [Gnu Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/). Whatever unnamed resource you're currently using, it has been measured, and clearly found wanting.

Comment: oh i forgot to exclude that line Thomas it wasn't required.
@craig , thanks i will have a look at it.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots in SO questions, at least not for programming problems that aren't related to GUI tools.  Also, you say "_so far not working_" but that doesn't help us understand what's wrong.  The makefile you have looks like it will work (it's definitely not a great makefile, but it will work).  So, please show (via cut and paste, not text description!) exactly what commands you typed and what results you got, and why you think they are wrong and/or what you expected instead.

Comment: @Madscientist , sorry about that . Thing is if i place that Makefile inside src , it creates a .exe file . 
https://prnt.sc/vpCg43C4TlVW - here's the view

next when i type Test in panel i get error : 

https://prnt.sc/r1Cyme1M7Qqh

i wanted to display "Hello world" after compilation is done

Comment: do i have to create a .h file and include .c file in it and try to compile .h file ?

Comment: Please stop posting images of text.  Instead use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73262907/edit) facility to add the relevant information to your post in the correct format.

Comment: Here's a similar question from today: [Is there a way to have all my object files in the same directory using Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73261712/5382650)

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually follow links but I was curious so I did so.  Your problem isn't related to make or makefiles or how your code is built.  As best as can be determined from the screenshots, all that is fine.

The problem is that when you try to run the program, it's not found.

When the shell tries to run a program it looks in the directories contained in the `PATH` environment variable, and *only* there.  It won't look in the current directory, unless the current directory is on the `PATH`.

So when you type the name of a program without a pathname to tell the shell where to find it, such as `Test` (by the way it's not a good idea to call your program `Test` because there is a system program named `test` on POSIX systems and it can cause confusion), it will search the directories on `PATH` for `Test`, and if the program is not found there it will fail.

If you don't want to rely on `PATH` you need to give the shell the pathname of the program you want to run.  So you can run `.\Test` instead (on POSIX systems it would be `./Test`), to tell the shell that you want to run `Test` from the current directory.